# how to send mass email without showing addresses but showing name outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

Anyone know how to send mass email without showing addresses but showing name outlook instead?

[image]

```
from To: email address
To   To: Name
```

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

No, the address fields must contain valid email-addresses. How else is the mail-system to determine where to send the mails ? It can only get that info from these fields.

If your intend is to hide the email-addresses, so other recipients can't see who else is on the email-list, then put the email-addresses in the BCC: field.  That is exactly what the BCC: field is for.

(You use Outlook: Normally BCC: doesn't show in Outlook, but you can set an option to show "all available fields" in the header.)